# Listing HTML files on my Google Site using Google.Apis and c#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm wanting to list all the pages on my google site using the Google.Apis.  Using the Google.Apis.Drive.v3 methods, I'm able to list the contents of my Drive account, but I'm only getting one entry for my site - the title with a MimeType of "application/vnd.google-apps.site".  I'm using a service account to connect which seems to be working. Is there another way to interact with the files on a Google Site? Here is my code:

```
string[] scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata, DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata, DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts };

        //open the service account private key file
        using (var stream = new FileStream("appName-bc2d6ad1c3bb.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            //create a new service credential
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
            credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);

            //create a new Drive service
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "appName",
            });

            var files = service.Files.List().Execute().Files;
            foreach(var tmpFile in files)
            {
                //Only lists the site name, not the individual HTML files
                Console.WriteLine(tmpFile.Name + " : " + tmpFile.Id + " : " + tmpFile.MimeType);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to remember that a service account is not you.   The service account isn't going to have access to the data unless you grant it access.  Try going to your site and sharing the site with the service account email address.

Second are you sure these files are on Google drive?

Comment: If I look at my Google Drive under my account, all I see an entry for the site, not the individual files.  I'm not even sure how to see the individual files via the Google Drive page.

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible?

Comment: Google has APIs for all their other services, so I thought it just might be and decided to explore it as an option.  If it isn't possible, then I'll move on to other options.

Comment: Well I have been working with google APIs for four years.  I am very good at searching there documentation.   I have found nothing that says this is even possible.  I was just wondering if maybe you read about it someplace.  The only thing I have heard of is the sites api which only works on the old ones not the new sites https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/

Comment: Thanks for the information, guess I'll go in a different direction.